# JPA/Hibernate: On Delete foreign key constraint fails

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I am trying to design a OneToMany relationships in the database for ease of deleting data. But facing some error. I have two entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ALGOS")
public class Algo extends Base{

    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "algo", orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JsonIgnore private List<Evals> evals=new ArrayList();

    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "algo", orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JsonIgnore private List<Recs> recs=new ArrayList();

    @JsonIgnore
    public List<Evals> getEvals(){
        return evals;
    }
    @JsonIgnore
    public List<Recs> getRecs(){
        return recs;
    }
    }
```

and:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "RECS_T")
public class Recs extends Base{
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ALGO_ID")
    private Algo algo;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "EVAL_ID")
    private Evals eval;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "CONF_ID")
    private Confs conf;

    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "recid", orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<RecPubs> recpubs=new ArrayList();

    @JsonIgnore
    public List<RecPubs> getRecPubs(){
        return recpubs;
    }
}
```

It is noticable that Algo is parent table and Recs - child. So, what I am doing is trying to delete an entity from an Algo table, doing simply `algoRepository.delete(algo)`, but I am getting an error:

```
ERROR: org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`db`.`recs`, CONSTRAINT `FK9ux9oqx6yr66cva4ro6l8m63r` FOREIGN KEY (`ALGO_ID`) REFERENCES `algo` (`ALGO_ID`))
ERROR: org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionMapperStandardImpl - HHH000346: Error during managed flush [org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement]
ERROR: com.app.controller.AdminController - Exception during deleting algorithm due to  could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
```

Any idea, how can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Your entity declarations are correct. They work as expected. Sample app [on Github](https://github.com/manish-in-java/stackoverflow-questions/tree/master/39353245). Either you have not posted actual code or you are trying to use a non-JPA method for deleting entities.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. This is really strange, it is literally the same, but not working.

Comment: Can you post a similar complete project on Github where the error is reproduced?

Comment: The issue got resolved when I changed the cascadeType from ALL to REMOVE. Normally, as I understand from the docu it should not be the case. But now everything is working fine.